# Line breaking with `and/or` + babel

Tags: best-practices, hyphenation, babel

I have continuously come up with the problem of overfull `hboxes` because sometimes I write `and/or` in my papers.  For example, this phrase:

> To design and implement a biofeedback system for alerting patients
>   and/or health care providers about their current fall risk index.

I know you can set the word *providers* to the correct hyphenation by using `\hyphenation{pro-vid-ers}` and carry on, but I wish this was done automatically by `babel` (as it does it with almost everything else).  My guess is that the `and/or` part is messing with its capabilities of line breaking.

So, just to be safe: What is the correct way to typeset `and/or`?  Should it be `and or` or does LaTeX have any specific way to deal with this?

**UPDATE**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[outer=25mm,inner=35mm,vmargin=20mm,includehead,includefoot,headheight=15pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}    

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=\parindent]
    \item To design and implement a biofeedback system for alerting patients and/or health care providers about their current fall risk index.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would `and/ \unskip or` work?  If so, I would just put it in a `\def`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: How does 'and/or' cause a problem here?

Comment: @jon I'm not sure about it.  I feel it causes it because I have seen this before with some other cases where 'and/or' is present.  According to egreg "provider" and "providers" slip through the hyphenation algorithm of babel

Comment: Ah, I did not know about problems with the hyphenation of provider(s). (Note, though, that I think one should avoid hyphenating a word [only in English?] on the final syllable outside of rare cases.)  As for 'and/or' that is the correct way to write the term, though it too should be avoided outside rare cases; it is a convenient shorthand that can usually be better expressed in formal prose. E.g., the 8th Admendment: 'cruel and unusual punishment [shall not be] inflicted]'.  Surely the point is not that 'cruel or unusual' punishment is OK..? Or would it be better as 'cruel and/or unusual'?

Comment: @jon, according to google the word should be hyphenated as shown... I'm not an English native speaker, so I could be wrong (but check egreg's answer).  On the other hand, the reason I'm using and/or is because the system I'm mentioning is either intended for both the patient and the physician or exclusively the physician.

Comment: No, of course it *can* be hyphenated at those points (and not others); I mean from a 'typographical' perspective, I believe it is not recommended if the final syllable is something small, like a agent-noun ending like '-or' or '-er'.  As for the and/or, formal written prose would prefer something like, 'X is intended for either the physician alone, or both patient and physician'.  More wordy, perhaps, but more 'proper'.  (Tastes vary, of course.)

Comment: When I take your MWE and turn the `/` of `and/or` into a space, it still overruns the margin.  So are we confident the problem is `and/or`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Nope, we are not confident... it seems the problem is with the word *providers*.  Nevertheless, I have seen that when using oneword/otherword LaTeX has problems with the hyphenation of the sentence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel provides `\slash` for this case, so

```
and\slash or
```

is the answer. But, please, avoid this ugly and unnecessary locution.

The definition of `\slash` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 467:
\def\slash{/\penalty\exhyphenpenalty} % a `/' that acts like a `-'
```

---

The problem you are experiencing and that's summarized in the MWE, has nothing to do with the "hyphenation" of "and/or". The problem is that somehow the word "provider" (and also "providers") slips through the hyphenation patterns for (American) English and so TeX is unable to hyphenate it.

It's not even in the hyphenation exception list stored on CTAN and in TeX distribution as `ushyphex.tex`. So you have to manually add a hyphenation for it to your document preamble:

```
\hyphenation{pro-vid-er pro-vid-ers}
```

would be correct according to Merriam-Webster.

How to find this information? If you compile you document and look in the `log` file, you'll find

```
Overfull \hbox (3.02989pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--16
[]\T1/ptm/m/n/10.95 To de-sign and im-ple-ment a biofeed-back sys-tem for alert
-ing pa-tients and/or health care providers
```

The `Overfull \hbox` messages always show the hyphenation points TeX is able to find for the words in the problematic line, so the difficulty with "provider" is self-evident.

For technical/scientific documents, it can be recommended to load the American English hyphenation exception dictionary:

```
\input{ushyph}
```

in the preamble will do. If some words still give problems, add hyphenation exceptions yourself as indicated.

Comment: I'm sorry, still not working...  The only thing that seems to work is to use the `\hyphenation` command

Comment: @MarioS.E. -- Without a minimal example it is hard to see whether TeX *would* break at the `and\slash or` or thinks that would lead to too bad a paragraph.... (And it does break on a basic `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` document with nothing else loaded.)

Comment: I'm adding the MWE :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton This seems to be a candidate for inclusion in `ushyphex.tex`

Answer (score 1):

You hit another point: English is usually translated with `\righthyphenmin=3` as the length of „or“ is smaller than 3. Using `\righthyphenmin=2` additionally to the egreg's solution should solve your problem.

Comment: TeX won't hyphenate a "word" containing `/` (past the slash).

Comment: You are right. Nevertheless, this is the mechanism jon refers to. \righthyphenmin is set to 3 in English while it's usually 2 in German. This honours the fact that in English hyphenation is easier to avoid than in other languages, e.g, German. Despite this fact, it may be just a convention.